# How to calculate poisson approximation?

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, p-value, poisson-distribution

I have a p-value definition as follows and I would like to implement it.

[image]

The values of n1, n2, n3, n4, n5 and N are as follows.

```
n1 = 102
n2 = 95
```

Calculating λ:

```
n3 = 1350
n4 = 3588
n5 = 886
N = 10382
```

So my λ would be 421.41

I followed `scipy.stats.poisson` documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.poisson.html

```
from scipy.stats import poisson
```

However, scipy provides number of methods to calculate poisson value as;

```
rvs(mu, loc=0, size=1, random_state=None)   Random variates.
pmf(k, mu, loc=0)   Probability mass function.
etc.
```

I am still not sure what method I should use to get the summation of poisson vales from `i = n1+n2, ...., ∞`.

**NOTE: I am not limited to `scipy` and would like to receive answers using python or R.**

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The p-value definition that you want to implement is the probability that a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda$ is greater than $n_{1} + n_{2}$. If $X\sim Poisson(\lambda)$, then $\sum_{i=n_{1} + n_{2}}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{i}}{i!}=\mathbb{P}(X \geq n_{1} + n_{2}) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X \leq n_{1} + n_{2} - 1)$.

In R, you can use the *ppois(q, lambda, lower.tail)* function with $q = n_{1} + n_{2}$, $lambda = \lambda$ and  lower.tail = FALSE to calculate $\mathbb{P}(X \geq n_{1} + n_{2})$.

I have never used Python, but the page you link to has two function that I think that you can use. You can use the *cdf(k, mu, loc=0)* function with $k = n_{1} + n_{2}-1$ and $mu = \lambda$. Alternatively, you can use the *sf(k, mu, loc=0)* function with $k = n_{1} + n_{2}$ and $mu = \lambda$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate your recommendations in python :)